# Set the value of multiple dropdownlist's with jQuery using parent

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a number of dropdown lists on a page (number depends on datasource) and want to be able to set the value of the lists based on a parent dropdown list. I suspect there is a way to do this with .each jQuery function but i am unsure of the syntax. Each of my dropdown lists has an id of list+id (e.g. list6) so setting the value when the function is called should not be an issue.

Comment: Can you show us an example of your generated html?

Comment: Please be more clear and add some code.

Answer (score 0):

If every option has an id, then you code simply set the selected attribute of the particular option.

```
$("#list6").attr('selected','selected');
```

Or you could also assign the value of the desired option to the dropdown list.

```
$("#dropdownlist").val($("#list6").val());
```